# How to make horizontal cumulative histogram (from largest number to the smallest) using Plotly in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, r-plotly

I am making a cumulative histogram using plotly package in R and below is the chart.

[image]

I am wondering how to convert it to a horizontal cumulative histogram and plot from the largest number to the smallest (top to the bottom). For example, 11 to 1 instead of 1 to 11.

The reason I am asking is because the largest numbers only have a few records, it will be more clear to show the larger numbers from the top if we plot the histogram horizontally.

I also tried plot a bar chart for the same data as bar chart can be plotted horizontally by specifying `orientation = 'h'`, however, bar chart cannot be cumulative.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

In `ggplot` you can do it with `coord_flip()`

```
require(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(disp)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = cumsum(..count..)),
                 binwidth = 1, boundary = 0) + 
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

And to reverse the order you can use `scale_x_reverse()`:

```
mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(disp)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = cumsum(..count..)),
                 binwidth = 1, boundary = 0) + 
  coord_flip() +
  scale_x_reverse()
```

[image]